# Binding 2 models

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views, sproutcore-controllers

I have two models and one view, but can not find the proper way how to `combine/join` the models.

Both Sproutcore models (Employee data) have an attribute `function description` . But the currently used model `function description` is out of date, so I need to use the `function description` of the other model.

```
functieLabel: function(){
    var bsnInt = parseInt(this.get('bsn'));
    if (SC.none(bsnInt)) return 'loading...';
    //var query = SC.Query.local(App.Medewerker, { conditions: 'bsn = bsnParam'}, {parameters: bsnParam = bsnInt});
    var query = SC.Query.local(App.Medewerker, { conditions: 'bsn = %{bsnParam}'}, {parameters: { bsnParam: bsnInt } });       
    var results = App.store.find(query);
    SC.info('results: length=%@', results.length());
    SC.info('functie: functie=%@',results.objectAt(0).get("functie"))
    var functie = results.objectAt(0).get("functie");
    return functie
}.property('functieLabel'),
```

I extended MedewerkerDetailInfo with a computed property functieLabel.
But the query is not correct, that is, all records are return. Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
    App.MedewerkerDetailInfo = SC.Record.extend({
    ..
    functieLabel: function() {
    ..
    }.property('functieLabel'),
    ..

    App.Medewerker = SC.Record.extend({
    ..
    functie: SC.Record.attr
```

This one is working as expected:

```
functieLabel: function(){
    var bsnInt = parseInt(this.get('bsn'));
    if (SC.none(bsnInt)) return 'loading...';
    var query = SC.Query.local(App.Medewerker, {conditions: "bsn = %@", parameters: [bsnInt]});
    var results = Sea.store.find(query);
    var lengte = results.length()
    if (lengte = 0){
        return "onbepaald".toString()
    }
    else {
        return results.getEach("functie").toString()
        }

}.property('bsn'),
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the situation? Is it possible for example to replace the old model with the new one? Is it possible to remap the property by using a attribute key, such as through `myProp: SC.Record.attr(String, { key: 'my_prop' })`?

Comment: I want to use the old model except for one attribute. The attribute "bsn" can be used to join. Do you perhaps have an short example of the above mentioned SC.Record.attr?  I use Employee and Medewerker. Both are used in several views in my application, and Employee has an outdated function description. As stated, the new view needs a combination of both models.
profit: SC.Record.fetch or attr ('MyApp.Medewerker', {key:'bsn', rel:'bsn', queryKey:null}), And do I need relationships?

Comment: A Model in SC uses SC.Record.attr to describe the property on the plain JS object in the store that are to be bindable within the application. By defining the type and extra options (such as key or defaultValue) you can define how the bindable property will be translated to the plain JS object underneath. (See also https://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.RecordAttribute&src=false).

Comment: The easiest way to solve your problem is probably a computed property which looks up the other record in the store, and returns the attribute you'd want to display. Relationships can only be used if there exists a relation on the record data, such as an id of the related record, or a nested object or array.

Comment: I added to computed property code, but unfortunately the used query is returning all records.

Comment: The conditions for the query does not have the correct syntax.
`var query = SC.Query.local(App.Medewerker, { 
  conditions: 'bsn = %{bsnParam}'}, 
  parameters: {
    bsnParam: bsnInt
  }
});`
Moreover, it is not a clever idea to make the functieLabel property cache dependent on itself. The parameters to the .property() function are the other properties on the object which make the system rerun the function whenever they change.

Comment: Thanks, the number of open and closing brackets are not equal, should there be an extra "{" before "parameters"? And I do not understand the ".. dependent on itself .." sentence. I have two models, and functieLabel is added as property to one, and is supposed to "lookup" the function in the other. Anyway, the new query is still returning all the records of the second model.  I added the models above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have got a working property, see above.

Comment: The way you use SC.Query.local(), it takes two parameters: first is a model, the second is an options object. The options consist of an object having at least a conditions property containing a string and a parameters property containing an object. You can use named items in the conditions string, see the documentation at https://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.Query&method=.local&src=false. Please add your working solution as an answer to this question.

Comment: As an answer to the property dependency: Function#property takes one or more parameters, describing the properties on which this computed property depends for its value. In your case, this means that SC will automatically re-evaluate the computed property when a change has been detected on the 'bsn' property of the same record. In your case I would also mark this computed property cacheable, by adding the .cacheable() call after the .property('bsn') call

Comment: The working code was already there, I will add the cacheable function. Thx, a lot.